# Regular Expression in Google Analytics for two parts of string

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to filter data in Google Analytics based on a regular expression.

I need to say "If the string contains "/secure//secure/common/callback" AND, further down the string contains the words "true" then include it.

I tried this: `^/secure//secure/common/callback*true`

I added to start to say there is a bunch of text in between "callback" and "true" but it returns zero when it should return thousands of records.

What regular expression would I use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
^/secure//secure/common/callback.*?true
```

`.` means any character
`.*` means any character repeated O or more times
`.*?` has same meaning except that it is not greedy, it matches the less amount of characters as possible, usefull if you have more than one matching (`true` in this case) in your string.

Comment: Yes!Thanks a lot @M42 this little snippet really helps me out